# react-native-document-picker uri to get rael path get

Tags: file-upload, react-native

how to get react-native-document-picker uri to get rael path

react-native-document-picker 
 res is=--  size: 76711
name: "IMG-20200420-WA0000.jpg"
type: "image/jpeg"
uri: "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A551098"

but i want uri to path like  path: "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG20200419175011.jpg  or can upload on server

Answer (score 0):

[react-native-real-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-real-path) will be helpful in this.

```js
RNGRP.getRealPathFromURI(image.path)
    .then(filePath => {
        let data = convertToFile(
            filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1),
            image.path
        );
        this.isImageUriOrNot = false
        this.setState({
            imageData: data,
            imageUri: { uri: image.path },
            loadCameraScreen: false,
        });
    })
```

Comment: this plugin make error at build time because no loger update two year i am using latest version react , so please any idea about any type file preview and  upload ,... not  only image ... all type must

Comment: It works perfectly in my ` "react-native": "^0.61.5"`. Can you please share your version?

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.62.2    how to install react-native-real-path  please give me steps

Comment: You will find steps on this URL https://github.com/swathysubhash/react-native-real-path

Comment: when fallow steps it give me  error   ---- C:\Users\ss\swc3\android\app\src\main\java\com\swcpro\MainActivity.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
              ^
  symbol:   class List
  location: class MainActivity

      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(          error

Comment: are you have any other option to upload pick file and upload

Comment: No sorry, I don't have any other option. However, I would suggest solving this issue will really helpful.